# Two foreign key fields to one model as an inline in the Admin

Tags: django

I have an artist which has a primary and a secondary contact. I would like to add these two contacts from the Artist admin. But right now both fields are clashing. Any ideas? Thanx in advance.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField('Full name', max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField('Phonenumber', max_length=255)
```

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(choices=COUNTRIES, max_length=32)
    contact_1 = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name = '+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_2 = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name = '+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Contactline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Contact

class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ContactInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is very clear when you have this type of inconvenience however I would recommend modifying your model and making a ManyToMany relationship between both models, because an artist can have multiple contacts, not just 2 and the contacts are not exclusive to each artist.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.fk_name